# php display date from sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently working on a page, where I've got a problem with getting the date from the database table.

It looks like, i have now an own kinda array for the datetime column.

print_r of my database:

```
        $projwebt = $viewmanager->getViewPageProjwebtProjekte();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($projwebt);
        echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
        Array
        (
        [0] => viewPageProjwebtProjekte Object
        (
        [id] => 1
        [projectnumber] => 1
        [name] => Title
        [progress] => 37
        [status] => 1
        [responsible] => user
        [customer] => user
        [definition] => 1
        [effort] => 15
        [priority] => 12
        [startdate] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2016-11-25 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => Europe/Belgrade
            )

        [targetdate] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2017-08-31 00:00:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => Europe/Belgrade
            )
```

works fine:

```
        <?php
        foreach ( $projwebt as $projobject )
        {
        ?>
            <tr class="<?=$projobject->status?>">
                <th colspan="2"><h2><a href="#"><?=$projobject->name?></a></h2></th>
                <th colspan="2"><h2><?=$projobject->definition?></h2></th>
                <th colspan="2"><h2><?=$projobject->progress?>%</h2></th>
            </tr>
         <?php
         }
         ?>
```

here it breaks, because of the **startdate**:

```
            <tr>
                <td class="responsible">Zuständig:</td>
                <td class="responsibleName"><?=$projobject->responsible?></td>
                <td class="effort">Aufwand:</td>
                <td><?=$projobject->effort?> MT</td>
                <td class="start">Start:</td>
                <td class="startDate"><?=$projobject->startdate?></td>
            </tr>
```

datamapper:

```
            $pageProjwebtProjekte->startdate = $row['startdate'];
            $pageProjwebtProjekte->targetdate = $row['targetdate'];
```

viewmanager:

```
            $viewPageProjwebtProjekte->startdate = $value->startdate;
            $viewPageProjwebtProjekte->targetdate = $value->targetdate;
```

when I pick the date to display (object oriented) it breaks.

So is there a way to pick the date element of the array startdate/ targetdate?
what do i have to set in my classes (viewmanager/ mapper...)?

I have no problem, when I try to display definition or effort and so on.

Thank you for having a look!

Comment: `<?=` is shorthand for `<?php echo` and perfectly valid

Comment: Try using format method() http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: Somewhere your code is converting the datetime from the database to a php `DateTime` object. That does not happen automatically, you are doing that yourself and you can format its value using the `format()` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for these informations! helped me a lot for understanding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a DateTime object, not a regular array. Do something like this:

`<?= $startdate = $projobject->startdate->format('Y-m-d'); ?>`

Comment: This was exactly the solution for my problem, thank you very much!
will keep that in mind, for the next time.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to echo the date from a DateTime object you should use the format method.

Ex. 
`echo $projobject->startDate->format('Y-m-d');`

You can see the documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php